# How to manually enable bootstrap responsive menu for small device

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I like to change the default ID name from `id="navbar"` to `id="main-navbar"`

```
From: <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
To:   <div id="main-navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

If I change then the main nav/menu items doesn't expand/collapse when you check in small device. How can I manually enable this feature? Please help.

Here is bootstrap template that I am using: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: What do you mean by 'items doesn't expand'? When I check that template on mobile device all works fine. What device do you use?

Comment: @jakob you try to remove this ID `id="navbar"` or change it to `id="main-navbar"` then thing will not work.

Comment: ok that's obvious because that id is targeted by bootstrap, but why you need to change that id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this button in code:
`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">`

So you change `data-target="#navbar"` to `data-target="#main-navbar"`

Comment: thanks for your help, that worked. In my page I have setup of main navbar and sub navbar, just to keep names clear to understand I change `navbar` to `main-navbar`

Comment: Oh ok, if it's 2 navbars then I get it :) You're welcome.